# PID of all child processes of a command

Tags: linux, bash, pid

In a bash script, I want to launch a process in the foreground, then print a list of all the process names and PIDs that were started as children of that process. For example, suppose I have the following scripts, but I can only modify the first one:

A.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
B.sh
```

B.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
C.sh
```

C.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running C.sh"
```

Without modifying B.sh, C.sh or the echo command, and without starting any of the child processes in the background, I would like A.sh to print the following:

```
B.sh 1208
C.sh 1210
echo 1211
```

Can A.sh fork a process that records this information while the child processes are running in the foreground of A.sh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** In the comments below my answer it turned out that:

> I need something that observes the creation of all child processes during a span of time. Given that, filtering to isolate my subtree will not be difficult.

... was the intention behind the question and it was for debugging purposes.

In that case I'd recommend to use `strace` like this:

```
strace -f command
```

`-f` will track child processes - recursively. Since forking and exec-ing requires system calls, `strace` will list any child creation plus the pids.

---

**Original answer:**

You can use `pgrep` for that:

```
run_process &
pid=${!}
pgrep --parent "${pid}"
wait # wait for run_process to finish
```

---

Btw, you may want to use the `pstree` command, it is nice to use:

```
run_process &
pid=${!}
pstree -p "${pid}"
wait # wait for run_process to finish
```

Anyhow, you'll need to install `pstree`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I do not want to start any process in the background. The & operator starts a process in the background. Is there a way to use `pstree` on a command that is about to run in the foreground instead?

Comment: How should it? There can be only one foreground process. But what is the problem with launch the process in the background? Added the `wait` command in my answer. That should basically work well for you. Except of one point, how will you ensure that the process has already started it's children in the moment you ask?

Comment: Forking will only give me the PID of B.sh. Even if I constantly poll `pstree` while B.sh is running, I still may miss some of the children. I need something that observes the creation of all child processes during a span of time. Given that, filtering to isolate my subtree will not be difficult.

Comment: AFAIK only the kernel knows that. If you are doing it for debugging purposes you might like to use `stap` for that. (means *system tap*, google it).

Comment: Oh, for debugging purposes it might be the simplest to run the process with `strace -f command`. `-f` will track child processes - recursively. Since forking and exec-ing are kernel calls, `strace` will list any child creation plus the pids.

Comment: `strace` works! Can you update your answer so I can mark it? Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) Updated my answer ... (PS: I'd recommend that you rewrite your question in a way that it reflects the actual problem. That could be two sentences at the end (just remove the rest). The problem itself is interesting but the question was a bit vague)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this with A.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./B.sh &
b_PID=$!
./C.sh &
c_PID=$!

echo "B.sh $b_PID"
echo "C.sh $c_PID"
```

The output will look something like this

```
B.sh 22802
C.sh 22803
Running C.sh
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I do not want to start any process in the background. The `&` operator starts a process in the background. So that is specifically something that I don't want.

Comment: @ByronHawkins If you don't start `B.sh` in the background, `A` cannot do *anything* until `B.sh` completes, let alone do what you want.

Comment: Its not possible for what you are asking Byron. The process needs to be forked

Comment: It would be ok to fork a monitor process that records the tree of subprocesses as it executes. But I don't want to fork the jobs themselves.